# Deep cloning a readonly instance

Tags: typescript, immutability, deep-copy

Lets say we have a class with a property that references another class.  I want to be able to deep clone an "Immutable" (or `Readonly`) instance of it:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'; 

interface IParent{
   name: string;
}

interface IChild{
   name: string;
   parent: IParent;
}

public class Child implements IChild{
   public name: string;
   public parent: string;

   constructor(props: IChild){
      Object.assign(this, props);
   }

   toImmutable(): Readonly<IChild> {
       return _.cloneDeep(this); //lodash deep clone
   }
}
```

While this code makes the first class properties on the `child` instance `Readonly`, the referenced object can still be edited:

```
let child = new Child({ 
   name: 'abc',
   parent: { name: 123 }
});

let immutable = child.toImmutable();
immutable.name = 'abc';  //not allowed
immutable.parent.name = 'abc';  //this is allowed!!!
```

Is there an elegant solution that would allow me to make EVERYTHING on the cloned object readonly?

Note:
Looks like `lodash` has a method called `cloneDeepWith` that takes a "customizer"... Wondering if this might be going in the right direction.

Comment: You should consider enforcing immutability by working with `readonly` properties. This makes your life much easier, because it allows you to perform shallow copies while still never mutating your original objects.

Comment: + nice side effect: shallow copies are faster and save memory

Comment: @ideaboxer ohhh so deep clone becomes unnecessary because, if the referenced object is immutable it doesn't need to be cloned?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Btw it is the way the [Scala language](https://www.scala-lang.org) works by default: All properties and local "variables" (constants) are read-only by default and still it is a fully-fledged programming language.

Comment: @ideaboxer damn... I just finished writing an ORM client to use in a react project.  In hindsight the ORM pattern doesn't play very nice with react.  Probably should have learned react BEFORE implementing the dependency lol

Comment: ORM should be fine with React, but not with classes but interfaces. Work with `{ ... }` objects and use interfaces to define their shapes.

Comment: @ideaboxer problem is that many of my ORM methods mutate the operating object directly.  Imagine you wanted to POST a new record to a rest service.  My method code would look something like this:  `let obj = new MyObject({name: '123'}); obj.insert();`.  When the `insert` call returns, obj will have a new property set called `externalId`.   Instead it sounds like the `insert` method should return a shallow copy with the new properties `spread` into it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154600/discussion-between-ideaboxer-and-nsjonas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to create a custom type `DeepReadonly<T>` that you would use instead of `Readonly<>`:

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
    readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]>;
}
```

This type will recursively apply readonly attribute to all nested objects.

[See this in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20DeepReadonly%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20DeepReadonly%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aimport%20*%20as%20_%20from%20'lodash'%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IParent%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IChild%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20parent%3A%20IParent%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20implements%20IChild%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20parent%3A%20IParent%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20constructor(props%3A%20IChild)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20props)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20toImmutable()%3A%20DeepReadonly%3CIChild%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20_.cloneDeep(this)%3B%20%2F%2Flodash%20deep%20clone%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20child%20%3D%20new%20Child(%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20parent%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22123%22%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20immutable%20%3D%20child.toImmutable()%3B%0D%0Aimmutable.name%20%3D%20'abc'%3B%20%20%2F%2Fnot%20allowed%0D%0Aimmutable.parent.name%20%3D%20'abc'%3B%20%20%2F%2Fnot%20allowed)

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
    readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]>;
}

import * as _ from 'lodash'; 

interface IParent{
   name: string;
}

interface IChild{
   name: string;
   parent: IParent;
}

class Child implements IChild{
   public name: string;
   public parent: IParent;

   constructor(props: IChild){
      Object.assign(this, props);
   }

   toImmutable(): DeepReadonly<IChild> {
       return _.cloneDeep(this); //lodash deep clone
   }
}

let child = new Child({ 
   name: 'abc',
   parent: { name: "123" }
});

let immutable = child.toImmutable();
immutable.name = 'abc';  //not allowed
immutable.parent.name = 'abc';  //not allowed
```

Comment: epic! FYI, the playground link you posted is instead taking me to .net documentation page

Comment: FYI, this solution has some big issues... discussed in length here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10725